# Git - branch from previous commit and split commit history

Tags: git

Is it possible to take the following setup and effectively split a branch into two branches based at a commit history?

eg: start with the following branch and commit history:

```
branch 1

git log:
commit 1
commit 2
commit 3
commit 4
```

Create `branch 2` at `commit 3`'s id and alter things to the following:

```
branch 1

git log:
commit 1
commit 2

branch 2
git log: 
commit 1
commit 2
commit 3
commit 4
```

Use case: I started a new feature on an existing branch not yet in master and committed a bunch of work to that branch. I want to branch off of the last commit before my work and take my work with me and leave that branch clean of all my work.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a `git checkout some_commit_sha` to go to a specific commit, and `git checkout -b some_branch_name` to create a branch from a commit and go to that branch.

Putting the two of those together, you can do `git checkout -b some_branch commit_2_sha`

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, but is there a command that will do that and revert the changes to that commit? Im wagering no, but I thought I'd ask.